# is my code on Heroku (free version) public or protected?

Tags: heroku

I'm running test application on Heroku(don't pay for it). Maybe I miss something, but answer me : is my code is private or anyone can pull it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is safe, only heroku stuff can pull it up and see, and it's free.
You should better read their documentation and accept their license agreement.

Comment: @Denys Medynskyi if this answer is correct use the check icon to selected as such. This will help you in getting more answers to your future questions.